# My CSS subclass isn't rendering, but the parent does

Tags: css, sass

I have a component `<WarningOutlined className="verify-icon__warning"/>`.

When I use the className `verify-icon` it displays the default, but none of the styles preceded by `__` render.

I've also tried importing an object from another file that's used to render a list of these icons and returning the component that way, but it also doesn't render.

I wondered if it's because I'm using two stylesheets in this file, but I commented out references to the other one and it still doesn't render.

The class is defined as such

```
.verify-icon {
    font-size: 18px;

    &__default {
        color: $color-dark-gray;
    }

    &__warning {
        color: $color-ant-gold;
    }

    &__info {
        color: $color-blue;
    }

    &__success {
        color: $color-primary-green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use plain CSS?

Comment: Do you have a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @HenryWoody I'm working in my company's codebase and this is sass which I'm not very familiar with as I've mostly done backend.

Comment: @Joel I think the only extra information you need to reproduce this is that WarningOutline comes from antd.

Comment: Sass needs to be compiled to CSS.  Are you sure your Sass changes are making it to CSS?

Comment: @barrett777 This component and classname are working elsewhere in the code base. It's just in this file.